# Use an empty TagPrefix with a <%@ Register %>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Though I can successfully do this at the top of a page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="me" Namespace="MyNamespace" %>
```

and then use a class like this later:

```
<Usercontrol:DataRowTextBox ...>
    <Regexes>
        <me:RegularExpressionValidatorItem Type="USPhoneNumber" />
        <me:RegularExpressionValidatorItem Type="InternationalPhoneNumber" />
    </Regexes>
</Usercontrol:DataRowTextBox>
```

**I really would like to do this:**

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="" Namespace="MyNamespace" %>
```

so that I can use it like this later:

```
<Usercontrol:DataRowTextBox ...>
    <Regexes>
        <RegularExpressionValidatorItem Type="USPhoneNumber" />
        <RegularExpressionValidatorItem Type="InternationalPhoneNumber" />
    </Regexes>
</Usercontrol:DataRowTextBox>
```

but that gives me the error:

> The 'tagprefix' attribute cannot be an empty string.

Isn't there a way to register an empty `TagPrefix` so it can be used globally without that prefix?

*The same concept, if I can get it right, would then apply to the `Usercontrol` prefix too hopefully.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and it does appear that the "tagprefix" attribute is a required, non-empty attribute.